# Algorithm to divide a vector R = 0:upper into a given number of subintervals?

Tags: matlab, vector, intervals

I have been trying to write a MATLAB function that does the following:

Takes inputs "upper" and "number" which are both positive integers. The program should take the interval [0,"upper"] and cut it into "number" subintervals which have integer endpoints and are the same length, except for the last interval (if the interval isn't cleanly divisible by number, then the last interval can contain less integer entries).

Then the program should make a vector x with entries that are the beginnings/ends of those subintervals.

---

For example, if I have `upper = 11` and `number = 3`, then the program should take the vector

```
R = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11]
```

and generate

```
x = [0 4 8 11].
```

It should first create subinterval vectors

```
r1 = [0 1 2 3 4] 
r2 = [4 5 6 7 8]
r3 = [8 9 10 11]
```

and then loop through `x` and assign `0` to the first entry and the endpoints of the `r`s to the other entries of `x` but I am at a loss as to how to tell MATLAB to do this.

My other problem is that I don't know how to tell MATLAB how to figure out if the interval [0, "upper"] is cleanly divisible by "number" and if not, how to then do to make the last subinterval shorter than the others.

I've sat at this for several days, but I'm not getting anywhere.

Any ideas or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated,
thank you.

---

I've figured out how to handle cases for when `mod(upper, number) = 0`, i.e., when upper is cleanly divisible by number. For those cases, I simply make

```
delta = upper/number;
```

and then

```
for i=1:(number+1)
   x(i) = (i-1)*delta;
end
```

Where the difficulties arise is when upper and number aren't cleanly divisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
upper = 12;
number = 3;
```

You can generate `R` using

```
R = 0:upper; % [0, 1, 2, ..., upper]
```

If `number` was a divisor of `upper` then the output interval would be `upper/number`. If not then this quotient should be rounded up, so there's a smaller "chunk" left in the final interval. So

```
interval = ceil(upper/number);
```

Now we just need to build the output array `x`. If `number` was a divisor of `upper` then the colon notation would give what you want

```
x = 0:interval:upper; % only useful if number is a divisor of upper
```

Otherwise, this will not actually include `upper`; we can handle the two possible cases in an `if`:

```
if mod(upper,number) == 0
    x = 0:interval:upper; % When number divides upper, this includes upper
else
    x = [0:interval:upper, upper]; % Otherwise we need to append upper 
end
```

You could instead handle this by subtracting 0.5 (or any positive value <1) from `upper` during the creation of `x` which would ensure it isn't included, and then always append it. Essentially forcing the `else` case above.

Then the **overall** code becomes this, note we don't even need to generate `R` unless you want it as an output:

```
upper = 11; % Upper limit
number = 3; % Number of intervals

interval = ceil(upper/number); % Interval size

x = [0:interval:(upper-0.5), upper]; % Create output
```

Comment: Thank you, this is extremely helpful not only in solving this problem but in learning how to clean up code in general. However, when I apply this to upper = 19 and number = 8, I get X = [0 3 6 9 12 15 18 19]; is there any way to still get 8 "pieces," e.g., [0,3], [3,6], [6,9], [9,12], [12,14], [14,15], [15,18,], [18,19] or X = [0 3 6 9 12 14 15 18 19], i.e., ALWAYS an X with (number+1) entries such that exactly number subintervals can be interpreted from it? (Note: I do not think this MUST be for the further purpose of this code, but I am just curious).

Comment: What algorithm dictates that you should have intervals of 3 until 12, then an interval of 2, then 1, then 3 again, then 1 again? There doesn't seem to be a consistent pattern to where you're putting your intervals - compared to the original definition in your question which was equal intervals except for the last interval which "can contain less", i.e. should always be smaller? By the original definition, it's not possible to have a solution with 8 intervals and integer bounds, so we end up with 7. You just need to update the criteria in a robust way...

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough in my first response.The prompt I'm following says that the number of subintervals should be ABOUT (i.e. roughly) "number," so it is also fine if they are less. In other words, your algorithm performs the task wonderfully! Thank you again very much. My follow-up question was nothing more than the result of mathematical curiosity. And. with what little mathematical training I have, I also don't see how it would be possible to isolate the number of subintervals to pre-set number every time. There's a random element to it all, depending on the inputs.

Comment: Sorry my reply was unintentionally blunt, glad the answer sorted you out! I guess my other comment was saying you could make it work for smaller intervals which are uneven, as long as it was clearly defined how they should be generated. Thanks